# this is very simple program of collection but not running

Tags: java, collections

I am using latest jdk to run this program. i cant find the right solution here pls help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class ArrayListDemo{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("abc");
    list.add("xyz");
    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.){
            System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Please explain in detail what problem you have.

Comment: only sharing code won't help you get answers. So kindly post details of you problem. What you want the code to do and what is the error/wrong output you are getting.

Comment: Please fix this one  while(itr.)    to while(itr.hasNext( ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a compilation error due to two things:

The contents of your class should actually be inside a method, not the class body itself.

The line with while (itr.){ should read while (itr.hasNext ()){

Answer (score 1):

You forget add hasNext() `while(itr.hasNext())`

Answer (score 0):

This will be right program

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

class ArrayListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("abc");
        list.add("xyz");
        Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

You can omit use of <> operator in list if you are using JDK8.